# view inside an image view hides behind the imageview

Tags: titanium

below is my code... the problem i am having is that may labelview hides behind the imageview when a picture is taken by the camera from the iphone device ...

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        title : 'Photoshare',
        fullscreen : false,
        barColor : '#000000',
        backgroundColor : '#fff'
    });
    // creating scroll view
    var scrollView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
        contentWidth : 'auto',
        contentHeight : 'auto',
        width : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
        height : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
        top : 0,
        showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
        showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
        minZoomScale : 0.1,
        maxZoomScale : 100
    });
    // creating parent view to contain imageview
    var parentView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        width : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
        height : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
        top : 0
    });
    scrollView.add(parentView);
    // adding parent view to window
    //  win.add(parentView);

    // creating image view
    var imgView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        width : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
        height : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
        top : 0
    });
    // adding imageview to parent view
    parentView.add(imgView);
    var labelView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        top : 280,
        right : 0,
        width : 200,
        height : 100,
        backgroundColor : '#000',
        opacity : 0.5
    });
    imgView.add(labelView);
    // opening the camera at the start of the app
    Titanium.Media.showCamera({
        saveToPhotoGallery : false,
        allowEditing : false,
        mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
        success : function(event) {
            var capturedImage = event.media;
            imgView.image = capturedImage;
        },
        cancel : function() {
            scrollView.hide();
        },
        error : function(error) {
            if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
                alert('Please Run it on device');
            }

        },
    });
    var currentLocationLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        left : 5,
        //  top : 2,
        width : 'auto',
        height : 15,
        color : '#fff',
        font : {
            fontSize : 12
        },
    });
    //  labelView.add(currentLocationLabel);
    var previousLocationLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        left : 5,
        //  top : 66,
        width : 'auto',
        height : 15,
        color : '#fff',
        font : {
            fontSize : 12
        },
    });

    var distanceLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        left : 5,
        //  top : 50,
        width : 'auto',
        height : 15,
        color : '#fff',
        font : {
            fontSize : 12
        },
    });
    var timeLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        left : 5,
        //  top : 18,
        width : 'auto',
        height : 15,
        color : '#fff',
        font : {
            fontSize : 12
        },
    });
    var weatherLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        left : 5,
        //  top : 34,
        width : 'auto',
        height : 15,
        color : '#fff',
        font : {
            fontSize : 12
        },
    });
    win.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
        var setTop = 2;
    /*  if (Ti.App.DataStorage.GetPreviousLocationVisibility() == 0) {
            labelView.remove(previousLocationLabel);
        } else {
            labelView.add(previousLocationLabel);
        }*/
        if (Ti.App.DataStorage.GetCurrentLocationVisibility() == 0) {
            labelView.remove(currentLocationLabel);
        } else {
            currentLocationLabel.setTop(setTop);
            labelView.add(currentLocationLabel);
            setTop = setTop + 15;
        }

        if (Ti.App.DataStorage.GetTimeVisibility() == 0) {
            labelView.remove(timeLabel);
        } else {
            timeLabel.setTop(setTop);
            labelView.add(timeLabel);
            setTop = setTop + 15;
        }
        if (Ti.App.DataStorage.GetWeatherVisibility() == 0) {
            labelView.remove(weatherLabel);
        } else {
            weatherLabel.setTop(setTop);
            labelView.add(weatherLabel);
            setTop = setTop + 15;
        }
        if (Ti.App.DataStorage.GetDistanceVisibility() == 0) {
            labelView.remove(distanceLabel);
        } else {
            distanceLabel.setTop(setTop);
            labelView.add(distanceLabel);
            setTop = setTop + 15;
        }
    });
```

Anybody can tell me what am i doing wrong ... Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential problem could be this:

```
 imgView.add(labelView);
```

Adding views to an ImageView has undefined behavior, it is considered a Non-Container View. For me this has caused my view to randomly not show, or be placed in a weird position. The solution is to create a container view, put the imgView in that, and then the labelView on top of it.

[The docs make an obscure mention of this](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-add), but it escaped me for a long time and caused many headaches, refering to ImageViews and other non-container views:

```
Adding children to the these views may be supported on some platforms, 
but is not guaranteed to work across platforms. Where it is supported, 
it may not work as expected.
```

General rule is to always check and make sure the component your calling `add` on supports it.